# Notating manuals and pedal on a pipe organ

Tags: notation, composition, organ

What is the easiest way to notate an original piece for pipe organ (two manual) and pedal? I would like to have:

1. The left hand play a tonal chord on the Great Manual
2. The right hand play a melody on the Swell Manual
3. The feet play on the Pedalboard
4. Have a cluster of sound on the Positive

Comment: There is a contradiction here. The first sentence indicates a two-manual organ, but three manuals are listed: Great, Swell, and Positive.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious question is how is the cluster going to be played, if the organist is using both hands for something else. Of course, you can use weights to hold down the keys, provided the organist has time to manipulate them. It's not entirely unknown for an assistant (whose main functions are to change the stops if the instrument doesn't have modern automation technology, and to turn the pages) to play a few notes when required!

But aside from that, it's quite common to use more than 3 staves for organ music that requires complicated registration. Split up the notation so that the music for each manual is on one (or even two) staves of its own.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question but you can notate organ music on MuseScore. You just create a new piece then follow the Wizard.

- In the first menu, you pick a title and all the other type of titles.
- At the second menu, you are given various choices in regards to
  templates.
- Here you have to click on the choose instrument tab.
- Click on the Keyboard header.
- Choose between Pipe Organ or regular Organ
- Choose A Key Signature
- And lastly pick a Time Signature, pickup measure and the amount of
  bars the piece has.

That gives you something resemble this which should be adequate for most Organ pieces. I don't know enough about Organ music to know if this is adequate to your needs.

[image: Organ]